# Transform Sql to QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I try to transform a sql query to querybuilder.

```
SELECT c.id, SUM(a.view_count), dt
FROM project_content c
JOIN project_content_analytic a ON a.content_id = c.id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT c.id, DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') dt, MAX(a.created_at) max_date
            FROM project_content c
            JOIN project_content_analytic a ON a.content_id = c.id
            GROUP BY dt, c.id) x 
ON x.max_date = a.created_at and x.id = c.id
GROUP BY dt  
ORDER BY `x`.`dt` ASC
```

I tried:

```
        $qb->select('c.id')
            ->addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(a.viewCount),0) as viewCount')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(a.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as date')
            ->innerJoin('c.analytics', 'a')
            ->groupBy('c.id')
            ->addGroupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC');
```

The subquery:

```
        $sub->select('cc.id')
            ->addSelect('MAX(aa.created_at) as maxDate')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(aa.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as ddate')
        $sub->innerJoin('cc.analytics', 'aa')
            ->addGroupBy('ddate')
            ->orderBy('aa.createdAt', 'DESC');
```

But i don't know how to join the queries.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does Symfony have an `outerJoin`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi and thank you for your answer, we have leftjoin on symfony.

Comment: Left Join is just a right join with the joined tables/queries swapped.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes. i'm checking on stackoverflow and it looks like its really hard to create a leftjoin with a subquery with querybuilder :(

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you think its possible to transform my sql with 2 query and use WHERE IN ?

Comment: Yes, given the right logic.  Alas, I'm not a symfony expert.